# Link MemoryFileSystem to Normal FileSystem in Java

Tags: java, filesystems, symlink

I have a FileSystem generated by [MemoryFileSystem](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem). I want to have a folder in the real filesystem that "maps" to a folder in the memory FileSystem, so any files created in either are just really written to the memory and not to disk. I've heard the term "Symlink" thrown around when talking about things like this, but I'm not entirely sure if that's what I'm trying to do. Is there a valid way to accomplish this?

I've tried `Files.createSymbolicLink(memoryRootPath, realFolderPath);` but that gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.ProviderMismatchException: expected a path of provider memory but got file
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any files created in _either_ are not written to disk? Then how are they created at all? This seems to imply a kind of low-level filesystem access that Java doesn't provide.

Comment: I meant that they should only get written to the memory filesystem, and not "be real" on the disk, just kind of looking at what's in the memory filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are trying to create the symlink in the wrong direction.  If you wanted files in the real file system to be "mapped" to the memory file system, then the symlinks should be in the real filesystem pointing to the memory file system.

But it is not possible to do that.

The real file system is implemented by the operating system, and it has no knowledge of the memory file system.  That means that the OS won't be able to resolve symlinks.  A symlink (in the real file system) has to refer to something in a file system that the OS knows about.

If you want to implement something like this, it needs to be done with file systems that the OS understands.  For example, on Linux you can create a "tmpfs" file system which is backed by memory / virtual memory.  You can then mount it on a regular directory, and create symlinks from the regular file system pointing to files or directories in the tempfs.  When you reboot your system, the tempfs will have been destroyed.

---

The reason that you are getting that exception in your case is an implementation limitation of `MemoryFileSystem`.  It is by design.

```
private AbstractPath castPath(Path path) {
    if (!(path instanceof AbstractPath)) {
        throw new ProviderMismatchException("expected a path of provider " +
            SCHEME + " but got " + path.getFileSystem().provider().getScheme());
    }
    return (AbstractPath) path;
}
```

In theory it should be possible to make symlinks work from MemoryFileSystem to the real file system, but:

- you would need to fork `MemoryFileSystem`, and
- I don't think it would do what you are trying to do.